# Which starting planets are shared with which classes?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

If I want to level with a friend, but we want to play different classes, which two classes should we pick so we start on the same starting planet?

Example: Bounty Hunter and Imperial Agent both start on Hutta.

What are the others?

There are a lot of resources for class X starts on planet X, but none that aggregate that data in one place so we can figure out which two classes we should pick so we can level at the beginning of the game (first 10 levels) together.

Comment: You'll want a dps healer and a dps tank for duoing, so for example, a dps specced jedi sage and a dps specced jedi sentinel, or a DPS scoundrel and a tank AC trooper (forgot the name of the AC) specced for DPS. Basically, both should be dps oriented, but have the abilities for tanking (one) and healing (the other). And lastly, you'll want them to be different base class, so you can get both classes' buff. You should also choose compatible crafts that don't share gathering nodes.

Comment: @Rodolfo: +1 for the dual-questing ideas. Especially about not contesting the gathering nodes. Side note on gathering skills: You can run to the fleet at level 1 and pick up gathering skills before you start questing on your starting planet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Sith Empire Classes

- Bounty Hunters and Imperial Agents start on **Hutta**
- Sith Inquisitors and Sith Warriors start on **Korriban**

### Republic Classes

- Jedi Consulars and Jedi Knights start on **Tython**
- Smugglers and Troopers start on **Ord Mantell**

Comment: Rule of thump: Force users share their starting planet, as do the non-force classes.