# What is the planetary leveling path in SWTOR?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

A friend and I are starting new characters. [We already know](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43108/which-starting-planets-are-shared-with-which-classes) which planet each class starts on, but we were wondering what happens after that.

Do the higher-level planets continue to cater to the same pairs of classes? Is there a point where all four classes meet up, or the classes swap which planets they have quests on?

Which planets have story quests for which classes?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Consolidating from [Powerlord's](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43960/what-is-the-planetary-leveling-path-in-swtor/43963#43963) and [Artein's](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43960/what-is-the-planetary-leveling-path-in-swtor/44157#44157) excellent answers.

For Empire, the order appears to be:

- Korriban (Imperial) / Hutta
- Dromund Kaas (Imperial)
- Balmorra
- Nar Shaddaa
- Tatooine
- Alderaan
- Taris (Imperial)
- Quesh
- Hoth
- Belsavis
- Voss
- Corellia
- Ilum
- Makeb
- Rishi
- Yavin 4

For Republic it's

- Tython / Ord Mantell   (Lvl 1-10)
- Coruscant              (Lvl 10-16)
- Taris                  (Lvl 16-20)
- Nar Shaddaa            (Lvl 20-24)
- Tatooine               (Lvl 24-28)
- Alderaan               (Lvl 28-32)
- Balmorra               (Lvl 32-36)
- Quesh                  (Lvl 36-37)
- Hoth                   (Lvl 37-41)
- Belsavis               (Lvl 41-44)
- Voss                   (Lvl 44-47)
- Corellia               (Lvl 47-50)
- Ilum                   (Lvl 50)
- Makeb                  (Lvl 50-55)
- Rishi                  (Lvl 55-57)
- Yavin 4                (Lvl 57-60)

Comment: This answer could do with an update with the planets that were added after the Shadow of Revan expansion (which added Rishi and Yavin 4). There have been at least three expansion packs since then, and each one has added new planets.

Answer (score 10):

For Republic it's

1. Tython / Ord Mantell
2. Coruscant
3. Taris
4. Nar Shaddaa
5. Tatooine
6. Alderaan
7. Balmorra
8. Quesh
9. Hoth
10. Belsavis
11. Voss
12. Corellia
13. Ilum

Something like this. But there are times that you're going back to some planets to do a quest or two.

Answer (score 9):

After your starting planet, the planets appear to be in the same order for everyone in your faction.

For Empire, the order appears to be:

1. Korriban (Imperial) / Hutta
2. Dromund Kaas (Imperial)
3. Balmorra
4. Nar Shaddaa
5. Tatooine
6. Alderaan
7. Taris (Imperial)
8. Quesh
9. Hoth
10. Belsavis
11. Voss
12. Corellia
13. Ilum

Note: I only know for sure through Alderaan because of where I am in the game.  The others are speculation based on the level ranges on the star map.

For the Republic, the notable changes would be starting on Tython / Ord Mantel and moving on to Coruscant.  Likely, Taris would also be changed out, but I don't know to what.

Comment: I can confirm this order up to Hoth. I think Republic has a different order, because I think it has different level ranges for the planets they have in common with Empire.

Comment: Speaking from personal experience, the only difference past the starting planets is that Taris and Balmorra get swapped around... Although given my druthers I wouldn't inflict *either* of them to characters who are almost certainly not level 24 and have a speeder yet.

Answer (score 6):

For Empire, the order is:

```
Korriban / Hutta     (Lvl 1-10)
Dromund Kaas         (Lvl 10-16)
Balmorra (Imperial)  (Lvl 16-20)
Nar Shaddaa          (Lvl 20-24)
Tatooine             (Lvl 24-28)
Alderaan             (Lvl 28-32)
Taris (Imperial)     (Lvl 32-36)
Quesh                (Lvl 36-37)
Hoth                 (Lvl 37-41)
Belsavis             (Lvl 41-44)
Voss                 (Lvl 44-47)
Corellia             (Lvl 47-50)
Ilum                 (Lvl 50-50)
```

For Republic it's:

```
Tython / Ord Mantell (Lvl 1 -10)
Coruscant            (Lvl 10-16)
Taris (Republic)     (Lvl 16-20)
Nar Shaddaa          (Lvl 20-24)
Tatooine             (Lvl 24-28)
Alderaan             (Lvl 28-32)
Balmorra (Republic)  (Lvl 32-36)
Quesh                (Lvl 36-37)
Hoth                 (Lvl 37-41)
Belsavis             (Lvl 41-44)
Voss                 (Lvl 44-47)
Corellia             (Lvl 47-50)
Ilum                 (Lvl 50-50)
```